Help with solving multiphoton and avalanche ionization rate equation of fused silica
I am trying to solve a rate equation that describes the evolution of free electron density of fused silica under action of a Gaussian Beam with peak intensity of $100 \,\text{TW}/\text{cm}^2$, pulse duration of $350 \,\text{fs}$ and FWHM of $175 \,\text{fs}$:
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = \alpha I(t)n + \sigma_k I^k(t)-\frac{n}{\tau}.$$
The constants are:
$$\begin{align}
a &= 4 \\
k &= 8 \\
\sigma &= 9.52 \cdot 10^{10} \\
\tau &= 60 \cdot 10^{-15}.
\end{align}$$
The above is the rate equation I'm trying to solve. Found in this paper as equation 3. Figure 2 of the same paper contains the expected evolution of free electron density when assuming only multiphoton ionization along with another solution when accounting for both avalanche and multiphoton ionization.
My code produces this graph when only accounting for multiphoton ionization:
Which is about what I expected, however when trying to account for impact ionization I get the following graph when solving using SciPy's solve_ivp using the Radau method:
And the following warnings and corresponding error when using SciPy's solve_ivp RK45 method:

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
return 4*P_I(t)n + P_I(t) - n/60e-3
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
return 4P_I(t)*n + P_I(t) - n/60e-3
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (1,)

Here is the code that I'm currently using that produces these results:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Constants
FWHM = 175  # FWHM in fs
I_peak = 100  # Peak intensity
P_constant = 9.52e10  # Constant in P(I)
sigma = FWHM / (2 * np.sqrt(2 * np.log(2)))  # Convert FWHM to sigma for Gaussian

# Define the Gaussian function for I(t)
def I_t(t, I_peak, sigma):
    return I_peak * np.exp(-((t - 175) ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))  # Center at 350 fs

def P_I(t):
    I = I_t(t, I_peak, sigma)
    return P_constant * I**8

def rate_equation(t, n):
    return 4*P_I(t)*n + P_I(t) - n/60e-3

time_fs = np.linspace(0, 350, 1000) 
time_ps = time_fs / 1000  
n0 = [0]

sol = solve_ivp(rate_equation, [0,350], y0=n0,t_eval=time_ps, method="RK45")
y = sol.y[0]
plt.plot(time_fs, y)
plt.show()

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Physics SE is not really up for debugging your code. That is software, not physics.

Should be a scaling problem, try to adjust integration tolerance constants. Print sol.message to see exact solver error.
